# Image exif/metadata reading/writing?

Tags: python, exif

Been looking around as there *still* doesn't appear to be a well documented and up-to-date for image exif/metadata manipulation.

I have the following code using `piexif`

```
import os
import piexif

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Alan Partridge\\Desktop\\images"):
    if not files:
        continue
    prefix = os.path.basename(root)
    for f in files:
        #print os.path.join(root, f)
        exif_dict = piexif.load(os.path.join(root, f))
        print exif_dict
        for ifd in ("0th", "Exif", "GPS", "1st"):
            for tag in exif_dict[ifd]:
                print(piexif.TAGS[ifd][tag]["name"], exif_dict[ifd][tag])
        #os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{} ID {}".format(prefix, f)))
```

It loops through folders renaming files depending on their folder name (commented out) but for now, it outputs whatever data the library can find.

At the moment, it can find `ImageDescription`, which is fine. My question is how would I go about amending it? Unfortunately I can't make head nor take of how to do this. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at samples at https://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample.html . You are missing whole `piexif.dump()` and `img.save()` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Image Exif information can be found in this document:

http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf

To use piexif library to build exif information, and write to a destination file: (python)

**Build exif info to preserve orientation from source file , which is read by windows to display it correct direction.**

**source: http://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html?highlight=save**

```
zeroth_ifd = {piexif.ImageIFD.Orientation: image_orientation,
              piexif.ImageIFD.ImageWidth: int(new_width),
              piexif.ImageIFD.ImageLength: int(new_height),
              piexif.ImageIFD.Software: u"piexif"
              }

exif_dict = {"0th":zeroth_ifd}
exif_bytes = piexif.dump(exif_dict)

with open(dest, 'r+b') as f:
    with Image.open(dest,'r') as image:
        image.save(dest, "jpeg", exif=exif_bytes)
```